# Is there any connection between instantons and surface-interacting polymers?

Tags: renormalization, quantum-tunneling, instantons, polymers

Excluded volume polymers interacting with a penetrable hypersurface of variable dimension is a very interesting system to study critical behavior via perturbative renormalization. Since a penetrable hypersurface for a polymer is a variant of Quantum mechanical tunneling I was wondering if there is any connection between this problem and instantons? Any reference to existing literature will be highly appreciated.